# Why is there no native string in both C++ and Java, just a class?

Tags: java, c++

This is more of a curiosity question more than anything, but here goes:

So I'm learning C++, and my friend is well-acquainted with Java and we went onto an odd discussion - why is there no native string in Java and C++?

Let me explain;
In both Java and C++, you have the primitive types, such as "int", "float", "double" etc. These aren't classes, and as such have no functions when you add a . after a variable name with that given type. However, (in Java specifically), you have the actual classes, such as "Integer" which are classes that wrap around the primitive "int" type. Yet "string"/"String" is a class from the get-go, it has no primitive type. Of course, you have "const char*" in C++, but what about Java? What is the primitive type for both of these? Is there a primitive type for String?

Comment: Because primitive types are crippled and should never have been there.

Comment: @rightfold That doesn't make sense. If int, float, and double was never in programming, there'd be practically no code that runs because so many things rely on it. Even the wrappers need the primitive type to be initalized.

Comment: Primitive types are supposed to match the physical hardware. So things like `int` and `float` map onto physical registers in the `CPU`. More complex types, on the other hand, don't need to be built in and so, in the tradition of `C` they are not. This is because the `C`  philosophy was to only put in the language what was absolutely needed and farm everything that could be done in a library out to a library. Its more flexible/extensible that way.

Comment: Because that's not the way they designed it. Pointless question.

Answer (score 4):

A primitive type is supposed to be the smallest atomic type which cannot be decomposed. A string is fundamentally a sequence of characters and that is why there is no string primitive.
Think of primitives as the minimum required for the language to function. Anything else that is required can be build from those primitives.

Comment: A string needs additional meta-information: how long is it? "A zero-terminated string does not" -- well, but the *terminating zero itself* is outside the string, so it also counts as 'additional'.

Comment: This definition breaks down for things like floats and doubles, which are not atomic on machines without floating point support. They are effectively sequences of 4 or 8 bytes that only the floating point library routines can parse.

Answer (score 1):

One reason why primitive types exist is performance. Primitive types in C++ map directly to machine types. That makes them system dependent. That is, `int` on a 16-bit machine will be 16 bits, but on a 32-bit machine it will be 32 bits.

In Java, the mapping isn't necessarily that direct because the it specifies that `int` is 32 bits no matter what. But still it will be fast on most modern computers.

In Java the `Integer` and other "mapped" types are used, where you need `Object`s.

There is no "string" primitive type in the CPU, so you won't get anything from having it in Java.

C++ *has* something like primitive strings, though. When you use string literals in the code `"abc"`, you're creating a `char[]`. This is an inheritance from C, which C++ preserves.

There are other languages, which don't expose the primitive types. They sacrifice speed for better consistency.